# What's wrong on my conditions ? Using the np.where statement to flag my pandas dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The function i am using is keep giving the red filter condition where not applied.

Here the function i am using:

```
tolerance = 5 
def rag(data):

    red_filter   =  ((data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'VESSEL') & \
                     ((data.latedeliverydate + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D')) < data.m6p)) | \
                     ((data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'AIR') & (data.latedeliverydate < data.m6p))

    green_filter =  (data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'VESSEL') & \
                    (data.M6_proposed == data.m6p) & \
                    ((data.latedeliverydate + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D')) >= data.m6p) | \
                     ((data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'AIR') & (data.latedeliverydate >= data.m6p))

    amber_filter =  (data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'VESSEL') & \
                    (data.M6_proposed != data.m6p) & \
                    ((data.latedeliverydate + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D')) >= data.m6p) | \
                    ((data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'AIR') & (data.latedeliverydate >= data.m6p)) 



data['RAG'] = np.where(green_filter, 'G', np.where(amber_filter, 'A', np.where(red_filter, 'R', '')))
```

Comment: I'd better stick to the native pandas mechanisms, e.g. query and where.

Comment: You have too many unnecessary parentheses, it hurts the readability but the condition for red_filter seems ok: `(MOT==VESSEL & (late_dlv_date+tolerance < m6p)) | (MOT==AIR & late_dlv_date<m6p)` 
This needs debugging. If possible, set a breakpoint in the rag function and evaluate each part of the conditions and combine them until you find the discrepancy between that and your expectations. If you don't have a debugger or don't know how to use it, you could at least "print" the values provided. There is something you're missing here.

Comment: the rag function don't return anything, and you use np.where inside another np.where, it is confusing.     How about put all logic in the function rag, using switch statement to return 'G' / 'R' / 'A' / " ', then use data['RAG'].apply(rag) ?

Comment: silly, python don't have a switch statement, I mean something similar to it, you know what I mean.

Comment: The problem is the encapsulation of the np.where statement

Comment: i found the solution by using the if else statement 
will post in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution if you guys are interested.
`np.where` is useful but would not recommend when there are multiple conditions

```
def pmm_rag(data):

    if  ((data.MOT== 'VESSEL') & ((data.m0p + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D')) < data.m6p)) | ((data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'AIR') & (data.m0p < data.m6p)):
        return 'R'
    elif (data.MOT== 'VESSEL') & (data.M6_proposed == data.m6p) & ((data.m0p + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D')) >= data.m6p) | ((data.MOT== 'AIR') & (data.m0p >= data.m6p)):
        return 'G'
    elif (data.MOT== 'VESSEL') & (data.M6_proposed != data.m6p) & ((data.m0p + pd.to_timedelta(tolerance,unit='D')) >= data.m6p) | ((data.MOT== 'AIR') & (data.m0p >= data.m6p)):
        return 'A'
    else:
        return ''
```